# Convergence of $\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$ with $x\in (-1, 1).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

By using the ratio test, I'm able to show that $\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$ converges when $x\in (-1, 1).$

I'm trying to prove the same fact using the M-Test but can't see a suitable $M_n \geq \frac{x^n}{n}$ (with $M_n$ independent of $x$) to use. Of course, I can't use $\frac{1}{n}$, but that's all I can see. What would work here?

Comment: Since the series doesn't converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$, there are no $M_n$. On every subinterval $[-q,q]$, where $0 < q < 1$, you can take $q^n/n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, that makes sense.

Comment: A remark: when it is convergent, the sum of this series is $-ln(1-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $b<1$ we have for $x <b$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigg|\frac{x^k}{k}\bigg|<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\big|x^k \big|< \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b^k = \frac{b}{1-b} $$

hence the series converges on $ [-b,b]$. For $x = -1$ it converges as it is an alternating series.